# explicit call to destructor is not destroying my object why?

Tags: c++, destructor

I'm calling the destructor to deallocate memory but it is not deleting my object. What is the reason behind it?

my code is like this:

```
class A
{
public: 
    int a;
    A()
    {
        cout << "a" << endl;
    }
};

class B :public A
{
public: 
    int b;
    B()
    {
        cout << "b" << endl; a = 10; b = 20;
    }
    ~B()
    {
        cout << a << b << endl;
    }
};
```

and I am using it like:

```
int main()
{
    {
        B b;
        b.~B();
        b.b=100;  // why this step is executed?
    }
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only called the destructor, you didn't use *delete*.  No memory got deallocated here.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Apart from cleaning up after placement `new` there aren't a lot of reasons to explicitly destroy an object...

Comment: Why the heck are you calling the destructor explicitly in the first place? And what do you expect to happen? The object was created on the stack and will not be popped off until you exit the scope it was declared in, so in your trivial case nothing bad is going to happen even if you operate on the object after calling the destructor. Also, after executing `b.b=100;` the compiler is going to call the destructor again because that is end of `b`'s lifetime (demarcated by the {}).

Answer (score 21):

> i m calling destructor to deallocate memory

Why? At language level destructor does not deallocate memory occupied by the object itself.

A non-trivial destructor ends object's *lifetime*, but it doesn't end the object's *storage duration*. This means that memory remains allocated, it just becomes "raw" (uninitialized). 
So, in that sense it is *destroying* your object.

Meanwhile, a trivial destructor has no effect at all. Even if you call it explicitly, the object's lifetime does not end.

In your case the destructor `B::~B` is non-trivial though, which formally means that by calling it you ended your object's lifetime. You destroyed it as much a local object can be destroyed. [But the memory remains](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5rZmUPDHCk). Attempting to access that memory as a `B` object simply leads to undefined behavior.

In fact, there's no way to manually deallocate memory occupied by a local object. Local memory is always deallocated automatically.

Comment: too bad the video has been removed :\

Comment: @AnT: I tried http://ideone.com/Oz0yoF this program. It gives me correct value of 9 as an outcome + 2 destructor calls. So, can I say that memory for an object still allocated for an test class object but it just may become "raw". So, it is undefined behavior to call t.get_a() after explicitly calling destructor & again when block is subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily invoke implicit destruction of the object. right?

Comment: @Pravasi Meet: *Storage duration* of your object is not terminated by the destructor call, meaning that the memory is still allocated. The *lifetime* of the object is over though, which means that calling `get_a()` on it is undefined.

Comment: @AnT you are awesome lot of things get cleared from this answer. Thanks

Comment: @AnT `there's no way to manually deallocate memory occupied by a local object` I got this but what's about __global object__ and  __static(keyword) objects__  I think we can't de-allocate there memory also manually. So I think only memory created in heap (dynamically declared objects with help of `new` keyword ) we can delete manually, am I right ?

Comment: @AnT __2.__ what is meant by __trivial__ and __non trivial__ destructor ? and now if we call __trivial__  destructor so it will not de-allocate memory so while ending the scope of that particular object automatic invocation of destructor doesn't come under `undefined behavior` right ?

Comment: @AnT __3.__  can I access member variables of object in it's destructor or it is going to `undefined behavior` ,  in another words at what time actually objects get destroyed just after starting of destructor or just before ending of destructor or just after ending of destructor ?

Answer (score 7):

You do *not* call a destructor like that (well, you *can* but it's generally not done).

For automatic variables like your `b`, the destructor will be called at some point when the variable goes out of scope. You don't ever need to call the destructor explicitly.

For objects allocated on the heap with `new`, the destructor will be called after you `delete` them. In this case, you also don't call the destructor explicitly.

C++03 states in `12.4 Destructors`:

> Destructors are invoked implicitly:
>
> - for a constructed object with static storage duration (3.7.1) at program termination;
> - for a constructed object with automatic storage duration (3.7.2) when the block in which the object is created exits;
> - for a constructed temporary object when the lifetime of the temporary object ends;
> - for a constructed object allocated by a new-expression, through use of a delete-expression;
> - in several situations due to the handling of exceptions.
>
> Destructors can also be invoked explicitly.
>
> Note: explicit calls of destructors are rarely needed. One use of such calls is for objects placed at specific addresses using a new-expression with the placement option. Such use of explicit placement and destruction of objects can be necessary to cope with dedicated hardware resources and for writing memory management facilities.

You *especially* don't do what you're trying to do since the destructor will be called twice, once explicitly by you and once implicitly when `b` goes out of scope. From that same section of the standard:

> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended. Example: if the destructor for an automatic object is explicitly invoked, and the block is subsequently left in a manner that would ordinarily invoke implicit destruction of the object, the behavior is undefined.

This text remains unchanged in the latest draft of C++11 that I have (n3225, November 2010) and it's unlikely it would have changed in essence between that and approval in August 2011.

Comment: For an object allocated with `new` you can call the destructor explicitly, and then call `operator delete` to free the memory, can't you? Or would that be invoking undefined behavior? (I'm not saying you should do this, but technically, is it possible?)

Comment: @paxdiablo __1.__ is destructor do memory de-allocation ? or after the destructor runs memory de-allocation done ?

Comment: @paxdiablo __2.__ because if we create user defined destructor and we not do coding in it still it is going to de-allocate memory

Comment: @paxdiablo __3.__ personally I feel after destructor runs, de-allocation done, am I right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: when you (non-placement) `new` a thing, the memory is allocated and then the constructor is called with `this` being the address of that memory. Upon `delete`, the destructor is called then the memory is freed. The actual destructor itself doesn't deallocate the memory for the object itself, but `delete` will do that as its final step.

Comment: @paxdiablo but what's about `local object` , we don't use `delete` keyword there for de-allocation. so how actually memory of local object is de-allocated, after destructor for that particular object execute while it's scope is going to end or program going to end ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: these should really be questions rather than comments, but the "deallocation" methods for various classes of data are different. Static storage duration objects are deallocated as part of program exit, `new`ed objects are deallocated by `delete`, local variables are deallocated when their scope ends. Note that only the second of those involves explicit deallocation, the others are handled automatically by the environment.

Comment: For example, the object `xyzzy` in the following snippet will be destructed and "deallocated" at the closing brace: `{myType xyzzy; xyzzy.someFunc(); }` Note the quotes I've put around "deallocated" since that term does not apply to the normal dynamic storage area (sometimes called free store or heap) in this case.

Comment: @paxdiablo finally I get clear in concept. basically I am confusing between destruction of object and de-allocation/ destruction of memory storage. Thanks

Comment: @paxdiablo  can I access member variables of object in it's destructor or it is going to undefined behavior , in another words at what time actually objects get destroyed just after starting of destructor or just before ending of destructor or just after ending of destructor ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane, you can access members from the opening brace of the constructor all the way to the closing brace of the destructor. The memory is not deallocated until the destructor exits. The process is basically `allocate, construct, destruct, deallocate`.

Comment: @paxdiablo yeah I can access but is this access is `undefined behavior`  ? as de-allocation of memory is not done by destructor right but what's about destruction of object ? So the destruction of object and it's member variables is happen at beginning of destructor or just before the ending of destructor . I think it can't happen outside of destructor as destructor is destroying object, am I right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: no, it's not UB, you can access all the members that compose your object right up until the point your destructor exits. You talk of destruction of the object but that's exactly what your destructor is doing. Keep in mind (for example) that, if the member is a pointer to something, you can still access/use the pointer. But if you've deleted the object *behind* that pointer, you can't safely dereference it. That's why I specified composition. The pointer composes your object, the object behind the pointer does not.

Comment: @paxdiablo sorry to say but I am again struggling to digest this concept I know I am troubling you lot but please forgive me.  __struct complex { private: `int a, b;`  `day d ;`  public:__ // some functions __};__  `complex c1` , see I want to know that  when destructor for `c1` runs when exactly object `c1` , `int` type variable `a,b` and object `d` of type `day` are destroyed. exactly means when __i>__  just after destructor called or __ii>__  just before end of body of destructor __iii>__ or else ?

Comment: @paxdiablo your comment on pointer I am not getting can you explain with some little code. `int x` __struct complex{ private: `int *p=&x;` public:__ // some functions __};__  means if  I deleted variable `x` then I can't safely dereference pointer `p` right. yeah pointer `p` composes object not object `x` behind pointer it's also right. I get it. but what are you trying to say from this I am not understanding ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane: I mean if you had done `X p = new X()` in the constructor (assuming `p` is a member variable), you lose the object behind `p` as soon as you `delete p`. However, you still have `p` itself up to the end of the destructor.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is actually invoking undefined behavior ... just because you've called the destructor, does not mean that the memory is zeroed out or necessarily "reclaimed" and inaccessable (especially in the case of an automatic variable that was allocated on the stack and not the heap).  It could be, but that is left up to the implementation, and typically that is not done due to performance reasons, which is typically the reason for using C++ in the first place. Therefore you can theoretically access the values at the memory address that the object was occupying after calling the destructor ... but again, it's undefined behavior, and you can run into pretty much anything from a segmentation fault, to a silent error that corrupts memory somewhere else, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's *executed* because *you* wrote the code that said you wanted it to happen. The compiler is simply doing what you told it to do.

What you're doing probably *doesn't* "deallocate memory," as you suggested it would. Instead, it just calls the destructor. Destructors don't deallocate the memory occupied by the objects they're called on. They deallocate memory allocated by the object (such as by calling destructors of member variables, or calling `free` or `delete` on other things), but the memory of the object itself is deallocated elsewhere, either by the internal workings of the `delete` statement, or by the compiler when cleaning up automatic variables (which is what your `B b` declaration represents). Even the closing of the scope block probably doesn't deallocate any memory for `b`; compilers usually figure out how much stack space they'll need for an *entire* subroutine and allocate it all upon entry. The memory occupied by that `B` object is reserved for `b` upon entry to the inner scope, and upon exit, the destructor is called automatically.

Comment: means when destructor of `object` gets called it executed and this signal( destructor executed for particular object) goes. Then destructors of member variable calls(something like that) and then it de-allocate memory. So all thing done after execution of destructor is part of internal working. am I right ? or something I messed up

Answer (score 1):

Your object has been destroyed but its memory space is still around until it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't? Your object has been destroyed but its memory space is still around until it goes out of scope, where it will be destroyed again by the way. It's undefined behavior to do what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Destructors were not designed to call them explicitly. Basically it is just another (special) method of class.
If you want to Uninitialize your object and then still be able to use it you could make our own method:

```
class B: public A
{
public:
 int b;
 B() {cout<<"b"<<endl;a=10;b=20;}
 ~B() {Release(); cout<<a<<b<<endl;}
 void Release() { cout<<"Releasing B"; b = 0; }
};

int main()
{
    {
      B b;
      b.Release();
      b.b=100;  // why this step is executed?
    }
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise B will be deleted when out of scope:

```
int main()
{
    {
      B b;
      b.b = 100;  //OK
    }
    b.b = 100; //compile time error
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    return 0;
}
```