# Explicit call to the destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, explicit

Can i still access an object after making an explicit call to its destructor?

for example,

```
class A{
        public:
            A(){
                cout<<"Constructor\n";
                x=5;
            }
            ~A(){
                cout<<"Destructor\n";
            }
        int x;
    };


int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    A obj;
    obj.~A();
    obj.x=4;
    cout<<obj.x<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

gives output

> Constructor
>   Destructor
>   4
>   Destructor

How am I able to access obj.x even after calling the destructor?
If the explicit call does not destroy the object, then what does it do?

Comment: What code do you think was exeuted when you called the dtor? What effect did it have?

Comment: Also define "destroy", with particular emphasis on data integrity and memory management ;-).

Comment: duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396059/explicit-call-to-destructor-is-not-destroying-my-object-why?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It calls the destructor, but it doesn't deallocate the memory. Memory will be deallocated at the end of the function.

BTW, if you don't understand what happens, you probably shouldn't do that: the destructor will be called a second time at the end of the scope, which may cause issues if it can't be called twice (which is often the case).

Comment: Even "deallocation" will (most often) not prevent later access to that memory, as little as a dtor call "destroys" the object.

Comment: You shouldn't operate a light switch?

Comment: if the object still exists ,then what does the destructor do ?

Comment: It runs the code in the “destructor” method. Destroying an object is a two-step process: call its destructor, then free the memory. Well, in general, because if you don't allocate memory to begin with (using placement new, for example), then there's no memory to free at the end.

Comment: In your case, the object is stack-allocated (you haven't used `new`), so it will be destructed (ie. the destructor will be called) at the end of the scope (the next closing bracket) and the memory will be freed at the end of the function.

Comment: @grv95 Define "exists".